# Extracting sub-strings with an extension of the last character

Tags: python, string

My intention is to extract sub-strings and extend them to the next two words within a large string. Below is string, an index list and output to provide clarity.

Example:

```
>>> _string='the old school teacher is having a nice time at school'
>>> index_list=[[0,8],[23,35]]
>>> [_string[x[0]:x[-1]] for x in index_list]
Output:>>> ['the old s', 'is having a n']
```

My goal not is to extend the sub-strings to cover the next two words. The last characters of the subs-strings should be extended to teacher and time.

Desired output:

```
['the old school teacher', 'is having a nice time']
```

If yo need more explanation, please let me know.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I need more explanation. How do you know how much to extend each string?

Comment: @Bach, thats the main issue.

Comment: My assumption is that it has to do with movement along white-space. Just my assumption....

Comment: So my recommendation is that you first understand your task, then ask about a way to accomplish it.

Comment: @Bach, thanks for the recommendation, perhaps its not clear enough.

Comment: do you need to find the substrings and extend them, or is the code you gave to extract the substrings also part of what is known?

Comment: @steabert, the code is only an example of how to find substrings within an index range. However, sberry has provided a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple enough way to do it...

```
>>> def tiger(inval, start, end):
...     base = list(inval[start: end])
...     spaces = 0
...     while spaces < 2 and end < len(inval):
...         char = inval[end]
...         if char == " ":
...             spaces += 1
...         base.append(char)
...         end += 1
...     return "".join(base).strip()
...
>>> tiger(_string, 0, 8)
'the old school teacher'
>>> tiger(_string, 23, 35)
'is having a ice time'
>>> tiger(_string, 45, 85)
'at school'
```

This assumes that you always assume words to be split on spaces (not punctuation - though a simple regex or character set could fix that).